# Proguard issues with jar files, how to find the missing jar?

Tags: java, android, jar, proguard

When I try to export my apk with Proguard I get a lot of errors (over 400) similar to:

```
Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
```

and

```
org.codehaus.jackson.xc.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.activation.DataSource
```

I am using the [Jackson Json library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), and the errors seem related to that.

Researching this error I found the following from [Proguards FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass):

> If there are unresolved references to classes or interfaces, you most likely forgot to specify an essential library. For proper processing, all libraries that are referenced by your code must be specified, including the Java run-time library. For specifying libraries, use the -libraryjars option.

Searching around on SO I found a lot of unanswered questions related to this, but the general sense was that the jar file I am using (in this case Jackon JSON) is relying on more libraries and they need to be added to Proguard's config file some how.

However, I can't figure out how to determine what jars are needed and where they are.  The warnings mention a lot of different packages such as javax.ws.rs.ext, org.joda.time, org.codehaus.stax2, javax.xml.stream, etc.

1. How do I determine what jars contain those packages?  For example, what jar is required for the javax.ws.rs.ext.** classes?
2. How do I figure out where those jars are and what path would be used with -libraryjars in Proguard?

Thanks much

---

**Edit:**  I should also mention that I am using an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) setup.  The jars are in the main Library project, and the actual working project has their build paths including the jars in the Library project.  Don't know if that makes a difference but thought I should mention it.

---

**Update**  Just to test, I completely removed the jackson far from the build path and from my code and now Proguard completes successfully.  The questions still remain...  What is the correct approach for handling these errors?

Does the Android export wizard in Eclipse automatically add the /lib/ jars to proguard or do they all have to be added manually in the proguard config file like this:

```
-libraryjars C:/Project/lib/somjar.jar
```

I did try that for the jackson one but it didn't make any difference.  Does this mean I also have to find all of the jars that are needed for the classes mentioned in the warnings and add those?  Would they be in the sdk or in the java installation?

Sorry if these are stupid questions, but I have been trying to figure this out for the last couple hours and have no idea what to do.

Thanks again

---

**Update Again**

So more searching, combined with Benjamin's suggestion, I found some of the missing classes were in rt.jar, which is in the jdk's lib folder.  So I ended up adding

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

To the proguard.cfg file and brought the warnings from 485 down to 204.  Hey I guess that's something...  The remaining warnings describe classes that I cannot find at all.  The app works just fine without running proguard, so these classes must be somewhere right?  Or are these warnings that I should use `-dontwarn` with?

The remaining classes are in these packages:

```
org.joda.time.
org.codehaus.stax2.
javax.ws.rs.
```

So now I just need a way to figure out:

1. What jars have these classes
2. Where are these jars so I can include them in the proguard config file

Comment: Jackson's very first page that you link specifically states that Jackson has **zero** external dependency.  Are you sure the problem is with Jackson JSON?

Comment: @Syntax, that's what I thought, but all 485 warnings are *org.codehaus.jackson.something: can't find referenced class something.else*   None of the other libraries I am using give warnings.   In answer to your question though, no I'm not sure the problem is with Jackson.  I just have no other leads at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had similar problems with Proguard and similar errors I was using an osmdroid.jar which built OK unobfuscated. This jar must have had external dependencies which my application didn't need. Fortunately the authors listed the jars needed and once I downloaded them and told Proguard via the -libraryjars option, the Proguard build was OK.

Re your missing jars (which you probably don't really need, but Proguard thinks you might!), you should find them at:

[org.joda.time](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/1.6.2/joda-time-1.6.2-bin.zip/download)
(The jar's inside the zip)

[org.codehaus.stax2.](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.0/stax2-api-3.0.0.jar)

[javax.ws.rs.](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/0.8/jsr311-api-0.8.jar)

Comment: This worked, thank you!  I downloaded them to a directory outside of my project, and added the full path to them in the proguard.cfg file like *-libraryjars C:/FullPathTo/JarLocations/jar.jar* and it finally was able to complete.  I'm going to leave this unanswered for the rest of the day in case anyone else has anything more to add about this issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I only can provide an answer for the first part:
Give

http://www.findjar.com

a try, there you might find the names of the needed jar files
[like so](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)

Comment: No problem! It's part of a [bigger project](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494) to clean up short links. I'm glad that someone finally acknowledged one of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the libraries for Proguard; you need to instead instruct Proguard to keep the class names and some other stuff. I toyed around with it a bit myself, and I ended up with something similar to [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/forums/forum/182456/topic/4867948):

```
-keepnames class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
```

If you're still experiencing crashes—and I would suggest testing vigorously!—you might want to keep Jackson completely intact with:

```
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
```

(Note that the latter produces a larger file.)